# GCP Billing API permissions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing

How to create and assign role having following permissions to the compute engine service account or any other user account

***billing.accounts.get***

***billing.accounts.list***

While setting up the permissions I am having an error as

```
Not applicable for project-level custom roles
These permissions can only be added to custom roles at the organization level; they have no effect at the project level or below.
billing.accounts.get
billing.accounts.getIamPolicy
billing.accounts.getPaymentInfo
billing.accounts.getSpendingInformation
billing.accounts.getUsageExportSpec
billing.accounts.list
billing.budgets.get
billing.budgets.list
billing.credits.list
billing.resourceAssociations.list
billing.subscriptions.get
billing.subscriptions.list
```

edit: could not set at organizational level also. having the same error

API: https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com

Error message:-

```
You do not have sufficient permissions to view this page
There was an error while loading /iam-admin/iam?authuser=2&folder=&organizationId=1010102021615.

You are missing at least one of the following required permissions:
Organization

resourcemanager.organizations.getIamPolicy
Check that the folder, organization, and project IDs are valid and you have permissions to access them. Learn more

Troubleshoot
```

I am the one who sign up for this free trail GCP account(i am super user), I should have all permissions right

Comment: Show the commands that are generating this error when creating and applying these permissions/role to the organization. Note: I would use predefined roles and not create custom roles for billing. Some permissions cannot be assigned to a custom role.

Comment: @JohnHanley error message added in question

Comment: On the Cloud Console, select your organization (not the project, just the organization), go to IAM & Admin > Roles and create a new custom role. You can search the Billing Account User role to get from there the permissions you mentioned. Of course, you can only do this if you have the appropriate permission at organization level, like administrator (viewer would not be enough).

Comment: There is no "super user" in Google Cloud Platform. If you want a permission (role) for an organization, you must assign that permission to your IAM member ID.

Comment: We are trying to create custom role for billing permissions(billings.accounts.get) but it is giving warning as it is not applicable at project level nor organization level

Comment: Also, those roles are for testing purposes and they are not subjected to any SLA or deprecation policy, so it is recommended not to create custom roles with them.